# Arrangements of AABBCCD

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

Find the number of arrangements of all the letters in **AABBCCD** in which none of the patterns **AA**, **BB**, **CC** occurs.

I've found Total Number of Solutions like that;

> **Total Number of Solutions** => $\frac{7!}{2!2!2!} = 630$

and I've fixed the **AA** to **A**, **BB** to **B**, **CC** to **C**

> *AA*  *BB* *CC* *D* => $4!(2!2!2!) = 192$

if I make `630 - 192 = 438` but the answer will not correct, because it finds the pattern which at least one combination occurs.
How can I find the solution?

Comment: n (AUBUC)=n (A)+n (B)+n (C)-n (AnB)-n (BnC)-n (CnA)+n (AnBnC)

Comment: You're counting ways that $AA$, $BB$, and $CC$ all simultaneously appear.  This is many fewer than cases where at least one of them occur.  For example $AABCDCB$ only has the disallowed word $AA$ appearing.

Comment: Also, there are only $4!$ arrangements in which $AA$, $BB$, and $CC$ all appear since we just need to arrange the four distinct objects $AA, BB, CC, D$.

Comment: Have you attempted to do this problem by using the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle?